# How to replace consecutive symbols using only one sed command?

Tags: sed

I have a simple .csv file with lines that holds 't' values. Here is the example:

`2ABC;t;t;t;tortuga;fault;t;t;bored`

I want to replace them to '1' using sed.

If I make `sed "s/;t;/;1;/g"` I get the next result:

`2ABC;1;t;1;tortuga;fault;1;t;bored`

As you can see, consecutive ';t;' have been replaced through one. Yes, I can replace all ';t;' by `sed -e "s/;t;/;1;/g" -e "s/;t;/;1;/g"` but this is boring.

How can I make the replacement by one sed command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is something to replace, branch to replace again.

```
sed ': again; /;t;/{ s//;1;/; b again }'
```

Overall, parsing cvs with sed is crude. Consider awk.

```
awk -F';' -v OFS=';' '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) if ($i=="t") $i=1 } 1'
```

Comment: Since the overlap is replaced by something other than `t` `sed 's/;t;/;1;/g;s//;1;/g' file` is suffice.

Comment: Note that the `sed` command won't work for first/last fields as `t` (though OP doesn't mention that case in the question)

Comment: Yes, you are right about sed and csv, no doubt. But I like to use the possible simplest solution under the conditions that I have. Thank you for teaching me `b` command. Now I can replace your code with the next line:
`: begin; {s/;t;/;1;/g; t begin}`

Comment: @vf58bwk4 you're digging yourself a hole by choosing the briefest instead of the simplest script. The awk solution in this answer is far simpler as well as probably more portable and more efficient and certainly easier to enhance and maintain

Answer (score 0):

Lookarounds is helpful in such cases:

```bash
$ s='t;2ABC;t;t;t;tortuga;fault;t;t;bored;t'
$ echo "$s" | perl -lpe 's/(?<![^;])t(?![^;])/1/g'
1;2ABC;1;1;1;tortuga;fault;1;1;bored;1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '2ABC;t;t;t;tortuga;fault;t;t;bored' |
```

—  `gawk`-specific solution

> ```
>  gawk -be '(ORS = RT)^!(NF = NF)' FS='^t$' OFS=1 RS=';'
> ```

—  cross-`awk`-solution

> ```
> {m,g,n}awk 'gsub(FS, OFS, $!(NF = NF))^_' FS=';t;' OFS=';1;' RS=
> ```

```
2ABC;1;1;1;tortuga;fault;1;1;bored
```